# Revoke file ownership and give user

Tags: server, permissions

In my Ubuntu server I have a user call cod accidentally I give ownership for inside of some sh file then I login as root and try to remove owership permison but can't.

```
sudo  chown -R cod4up:cod4up /home/cod4up/
```

when I type this I got this error

```
changing ownership of
'/home/cod4up/serverfiles/OGP_HOME_000000004_startup_scr.sh':
Operation not permitted
```

whatever I type I can't do anything. How can I give permison to user cod4up?

note: I try to login as cod4up when I type password I got this error

but i want to delete /home/cod4up/serverfile inside of this folder i want remove

```
OGP_HOME_000000004_startup_scr.sh
```

this file because it has a permission. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file that you want to remove? `ls -ahl /home/cod4up/serverfiles/OGP_HOME_000000004_startup_scr.sh`

Comment: all permission     i dont how to change to user  its block sudo commas also

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you please post the output of the above command (in my previous comment)?
What happens if you run `sudo chown cod4up:cod4up /home/cod4up/serverfiles/OGP_HOME_000000004_startup_scr.sh` ? (note that there is only 1 space between `sudo` and `chown`)

Comment: *"then i login as root"* - how exactly did you do this? if you logged in as root via the boot menu's recovery mode, then the filesystem will have been mounted read-only by default

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i install ogp(open game panel) that why that file block your owner ship

```
sudo chattr -i /home/cod4up/serverfiles/OGP_HOME_000000004_startup_scr.sh
```

use this code its will rove those file